# hashCode() that returns a specific code based on criteria

Tags: java, arrays, hashcode

I have been at this for days. Our assignment requires that I override the `equals()` and, more importantly, `hashCode()`. Objects to be compared:
Two-dimensional int arrays.
Criteria of `hashCode()`:

Any two-dim array layout that matches any rotated variant or the reflection of the rotated variant **should have the same hashCode**.

Visually, that would mean that if I had these two 2d arrays:

```
arr 1               arr2

[0, 0, 1]           [1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0]           [0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1]           [1, 0, 0]
```

The two following print-statements would be identical, since `arr2` is a reflection of `arr1`.

```
System.out.println(arr1.hashCode());
System.out.println(arr2.hashCode());
```

Now, I am quite helpless in how to implement this. I figured I would have to do something like this (pseudo):

```
int hashCode() {

    lastHash = listOfArrays.last().hashCode()
    variants = this.getHashVariants()

    foreach (variants as v)
        if (lastHash == v) return v
    return this.SystemGeneratedHash()
}
```

There is just so much that can and will go wrong with this approach, but I'm stumped and this was all I could think of. The idea of making the `hashCode()`-function rely on an outside list feels really icky too. The lecture on the subject was abysmal, and search engines have not been in my favor as of yet.

**Q:** How can I make **non-identical** objects return the same hashCode as long as they match a certain requirement?

Comment: Will `public int hashCode(){ return 0; }` meet your needs?

Comment: You are correct in observing that hashCode should NOT depend on anything external, and should be computed solely based on attributes of the object itself.  Try approaching it from a different angle by asking yourself what is common and what is different between the two objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possible solutions to this.  Here are four, just off the top of my head -

- Just return a constant.
- Add up the numbers in all the cells and return that.
- Take the absolute value of the determinant of the matrix.
- Multiply each entry by the distance from the cell to the nearest corner, and add these up.

This is limited only by your imagination.

Answer (score 1):

Well, honestly I would just use `Arrays.hashCode()`. You need your hashcode to be the same for any rotationally symetric array, so I would write a method which rotates your data 90 degrees, and one which reflects your data.  At that point your code is something like:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int[][] once = rotate(data);
    int[][] twice = rotate(once);
    int[][] thrice = rotate(twice);
    int[][] flippedData = flip(data);
    int[][] flippedOnce = flip(once);
    int[][] flippedTwice = flip(twice);
    int[][] flippedThrice = flip(thrice);

    return Arrays.hashCode(data) + Arrays.hashCode(once) +
           Arrays.hashCode(twice) + Arrays.hashCode(thrice) +
           Arrays.hashCode(flippedData) + Arrays.hashCode(flippedOnce) +
           Arrays.hashCode(flippedTwice) + Arrays.hashCode(flippedThrice);
}
```

That way, no matter the original orientation of your data, you still come up with the same ultimate hash code.

Comment: This doesn't quite work.  You also need to add in the four reflected matrices.

Comment: Ach, you're right, I missed that.  Updated answer accordingly.